# Как сделать следование за мышкой css?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы *.game__block* двигался за курсором. Без яп это можно реализовать?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.game {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.game__block {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Игра</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div class="game__block">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: без javascript - нет, нельзя

Comment: Да начните вы уже учить js. На языках разметки можно напилить только разметку, а не логику!